# Where to deploy complex .NET applications which include web and non web component

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, visual-studio-2015, program-files

There doesn't seem to be an obvious place or any documentation from Microsoft that explains where to install complex applications which write files into the app folder and are shared by different users.

We have a complex .NET web application that contains 21 individual projects and includes the following components:

- A main web site which runs a SAAS system and can be locally installed at customer sites
- Applications to install, configure and diagnose
- Applications which are installed as windows services
- Utility applications which are installed on the server and can also be installed on clients and talk to the web app through web services

On Windows 2012 and earlier, you could quite happily deploy this application into program files, and the entire app would sit in one folder. All fine.

However from Windows 2012 R2 and later, normal user accounts cannot write to program files. Our web app contains significant uploading ability, not only of occasional use files, but also a high volume of data files which are fed from customer LANs to our SAAS system. In addition there is log file writing, and session files etc are written inside the folder that hosts the IIS web itself (edit: and the webfolder itself also exists inside our program files app folder)

From what I can gather, apps now reside in program files, and common data exists somewhere inside c:\users\public, and user specific data exists inside c:\users\username. That means the app is spread around on the hard disk and not easy to backup or administer. To follow those conventions we'd need significant rewriting as a lot of the EXE's write relative to the exe path and the web backend also relies on being able to write files inside the webfolder itself.

So is there a proper place in Windows where a complex app like this can be installed that writes to its own folder structures ?

I've noticed on Windows 2012 R2 and Windows 2016, that I CAN create a folder in the root of C: drive, whereas on Windows 10 I cannot. Would a standalone folder be the right solution to this ? It would certainly be the easiest solution for us.

The windows services and IIS app pool would always run under different credentials, so they could no longer share settings if we have a per-user model for writing files.

The app will have to conform to DoD STIG standards for web and .net applications.

thanks

Comment: You can create a folder in the root of your system drive in Windows 10. I don't know why you think you can't.

Comment: I can when I do things to the system - I can't remember exactly what, but guessing: things like log in as administrator and turn off UAC, I think there were some reg settings too. Anyway, thats obviously a good option, but it does rather defeat the object of the security that exists in program files

Comment: I'm not saying you should put folders in the root of your system drive. I am saying that unlike what you stated in your question, it is indeed possible to create a folder in the root of your system drive in Windows 10. As far as where to put things, you can [follow Microsoft guidelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/) or you can put it wherever makes you happy. It's really up to you, and you don't need other people here to tell you where to put your files.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess the crux of the question is, what is the best practice when you have a huge application which contains EXEs and web apps and services, such that they all need to share settings data and write files into the locations in the same structure where the programs are installed.  The link helps in knowing the best practice for the different types of file, but not where to put applications like this. I suppose the underlying premise is that you do use programfiles, and you accept that data will be separate from code

Comment: Best practice is: use whatever works for your situation.